# Are wizards and witches in Britain really allowed to marry muggles?

Tags: harry-potter, marriage

In the Fantastic Beasts movie we find out that American magical community doesn't allow any relationship with muggles.

I think it's quite a sensible choice, considering that even the smartest and strongest muggle is completely powerless when it comes to mind-altering magic, which is available to an average wizard. It's not only dark magic either - Confundus, Obliviate (which it appears anyone can use) and other charms and spells come to mind, and I don't even want to start on potions.

Of course, wizards and witches are almost as vulnerable to these things as muggles, but they at least know about them.

We have a 'good' example of Merope Gaunt basically forcing herself on Tom Riddle Sr, and at least one example of a witch not telling her husband about magic until they are married (Seamus' mother) which seems like a very bad idea even if she had no malicious intent.

I'm sure there were a lot of other instances of magical people (not Death Eaters either) abusing muggles and messing with their minds.

The point is - muggles and magicals are in no way equal. So any marriage between a muggle and a wizard/witch should immediately fall under suspicions of foul play on the part of the latter.

**So do we have any information about legalities involved in a magical person marrying a muggle in Britain?** We don't have many conclusive examples. Was there any way for the muggle in question to protect themselves against manipulation and abuse?

Comment: *I'm half-and-half. Me dad's a Muggle. Mam didn't tell him she was a witch 'til after they were married. Bit of a nasty shock for him.* -  Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 7 (The Sorting Hat) - Seamus Finnigan:

Comment: @Valorum, thanks, I edited the part about Seamus. Still, a very bad situation. As for legalities, that doesn't tell us much. Maybe they don't care about this kind of thing in Ireland?

Comment: I suspect the Ministry of Magic would step in if Goyle suddenly announced that he was marrying Mila Kunis.

Comment: snapes father was a muggle?

Comment: @Himarm, yes, it seems like Snape and Seamus' situations point to the fact that it was legal, but were there any laws for regulating this kind of thing?

Comment: When magical children can be born to two muggle parents, a ban on marriages seems a little less necessary. Sure, there is the opportunity for foul play, but no more so than a kid messing with their parents.

Comment: @Xantec, seems much less likely for a kid to mess with their parents, especially since he/she wouldn't be allowed to do any magic before 17. Hermione was a special case, even though what she'd done to her parents was terrible

Comment: @ibid, you didn't post the answer yet - I was well whithin my rights to delete my own question according to the rules

Comment: Indeed, any relationship between a Muggle and a Wizard/Witch resembles [Statutory rape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statutory_rape)

Comment: Something about "really" in the title "Are wizards and witches ... really allowed to ...?" I found funny.  I guess it is the layers of reality we deal with.

Comment: @YuriyS - I'd say that the fourteen net upvotes indicate that the community approves of your question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Yes, this was dealt with by multiple ministry departments, specifically the Auror office

One of the questions in the Grade One WOMBAT test, which was designed to "test whether the sitter would be able to exist safely and effectively within the magical world" asked about which Ministry department to report these types of issues to.

> Question 1 out of 17
> Which Ministry of Magic department(s) and/or committee(s) would you contact to resolve each of the following dilemmas?
>
> Part 5 out of 5
> Witch F fed love potion to a Muggle man, who has married her. When you went around with a wedding gift you discovered that she is using him as an occasional table.
>
> ☐ **Auror office**
> ☐ Misuse of Magic Office
> ☐ Obliviators
> ☐ Wizengamot
> ☐ **All of the above**
> ☐ None of the above
> <sub>([W.O.M.B.A.T. Grade One - Part One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMNM7.jpg))</sub>
>
> [image: W.O.M.B.A.T. Grade One - Part One]

The quiz [gave four points](http://pastebin.com/raw/wx27jBS2) for "All of the above" and 2 points for "Auror office".

This would imply that these concerns were dealt with by the ministry, and that there was legislation in place to protect the muggle under Magical Law.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the WOMBAT test? I can't find it on Pottermore (if that's where it is originally from), and the other link is just a text dump of somebody's answers. The way it is right now, it kind of looks like fanfiction, although I'm guessing it's not :-/

Comment: @Thunderforge - They've been offline ever since Rowling closed her website in 2012, but here are  [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/mxWtj) of the first test. You can also find text copies of the test on HP Lexicon, HP Wiki, and Cos Forums. I only linked to the answers because they can not be found thorough a quick Google search.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any text saying that in Britain that you can't do it. It is frowned upon as you can tell from the amount of teasing received by half-bloods. The MoM could very well step in. So it is "Legal" but frowned upon.

> "You dare speak his name with your unworthy lips, you dare besmirch it with your half-blood's tongue, you dare... He dared — he dares — he stands there — filthy half-blood — " —Bellatrix Lestrange's prejudice against Harry Potter's half-blood status

^Order of phoenix

> Harry Potter and his children are half-bloods with known Muggle ancestry
>
> Those who believe in the importance of blood purity consider half-bloods to be inferior because of their Muggle heritage, though superior to Muggle-borns. Occasionally the term "half-blood" can be used in a derogatory manner, similar to the epithet "Mudblood"; Bellatrix Lestrange and the portrait of Walburga Black did so on multiple occasions.
>
> Some half-bloods expressed prejudice towards those with Muggle heritage, despite having some themselves, and clung to what wizarding heritage they had. Notably, Lord Voldemort hated Muggles and Muggle-borns, despite having a Muggle father, and denied his half-Muggle heritage, leaving hints that he was a pure-blood instead, emphasising his heritage to the famous pure-blood ancestor, Salazar Slytherin, to make himself more believable.[1] Severus Snape may be another example; his self-entitled nickname was "Half-Blood Prince" because his mother, Eileen Prince, was a pure-blood witch and his father, Tobias Snape, was a Muggle. However, Remus Lupin reported that he never used the nickname openly. This, as well as Snape's membership in the Death Eaters, suggests he may have been ashamed of his Muggle heritage, at least in his early life.[4] In fact, these people, along with some other Death Eaters, pretend to be pure-bloods, hiding their Muggle heritage from anyone else; most of them are half-bloods due to centuries of dilution and decline of what may be called as a true "pure-blood". Ironically (or perhaps because of), regarding the Prophecy concerning his defeat, Voldemort chose to go after a half-blood Harry Potter instead of the pure-blood Neville Longbottom.

[Source](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Half-blood)

Comment: @Edlothiad done. I added a source and a bunch of info

Comment: FYI the wiki is generally considered here to be a very unreliable source.

Comment: That is why I left the quote in

Comment: As in having a quote from the wiki is usually regarded as worse than personal speculation. If you can see where the wiki is basing itself off of, just quote that original source.